# How to execute grass module in QGIS python command console

Tags: python, console, qgis, grass

I am working under QGIS V2.16.0. I'd like to run the r.watershed module of grass using the python command console of QGIS.

I tried a lot of syntax like this :

`execfile ("r.watershed", "elev=D:\Developpement\Debits_cartes_alea\Donnees_test\exemple_mnt1.tif" )`

but no one is working.

Comment: `execfile` is not working because it is a function to execute a Python file, see https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#execfile

Comment: Possible duplicate. http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/182353/issue-with-r-watershed-run-by-qgis-python-processing-runalg